# How does a webserver using PHP resolve files asynchronously?

Tags: php, node.js

I understand that if we're using an asynchronous webserver like `nodejs`, we have the API call to retrieve a file asynchronously without locking the file. How does PHP handle this? For example, if there are a 1000 request coming in at the same time, doesn't `fopen` lock the file?

Comment: Why should fopen() lock the file? flock() locks a file

Answer (score 1):

`fopen()` loads the file into memory which allows other requests to modify it too.

You're confusing it being locked to the process. `fopen()` would prevent other processes from opening that file.

Comment: So wouldn't 1000 request spawn 2-3 php-fpm processes that tries to open that file resource at the same time?

Comment: Yes, which is why you don't that and, as another user stated, you shouldn't use `fopen()` and `fread()`.

This creates a bottleneck and makes it very VERY slow.

Answer (score 1):

When there is an HTTP request and the response will be a file,
 
retrieval of a file should not be done with `fopen()` and `fread()`.

Even though fopen and fread would not prevent multiple accesses to the file,
it would better be done with a single command:

Simple and **file open time is at a minimum**.
**Example 1 (fixed file name)**

```
<?php 
readfile('/home/user/file_to_read');
?>
```

**Example 2 (passed file name**

```
<?php 
readfile($_POST['filename']);
?>
```

This reads in the file and echos it to the caller.  It is also binary safe.

If the file contains only string data then file_get_contents() could be used.

```
<?php 
echo file_get_contents($_POST['filename']);
?>
```